# Inject list of components into a Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a bunch of components that implement an interface, IConverters. I want to inject them in the creation of a Bean, but currently i had no success.

I tried with field injection, but it blows up and fails to collect the components into a List

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionConfig {

    @Inject
    private List<IConverters> converters;

    @Bean
    public @Qualifier("dataConversionService") DefaultConversionService dataConversionService() {
        DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        for (IConverters converter : converters) {
            converter.register(conversionService);
        }
        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

And my components look like this

```
@Component
@Qualifier("languageConverters")
public class LanguageConverters implements IConverters<Language, example.persistence.jooq.tables.pojos.Language, Long, LanguageOutput>{

    public LanguageConverters() {
    }

    ...
}
```

But if fails reporting `No qualifying bean of type IConverter<?, ?, ?, ?>`. How can I inject the list, so that the next person just implements the interface and with the right annotations, the converters get into the list?

Comment: You have a raw type on `List<IConverters>`...

Comment: What do you mean by "blows up and fails to collect the components into a List"? Do you have any stack trace?

Comment: Are your `IConverter` implemented objects in a package that is being used for component scanning?

Comment: @Strelok yeah, i ended up reordering the basePackages array in the initial ComponentScan, so that my converters would get scanned first, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you can do it
Suppose you have an interface IService
Implemented by 2 class AService and BService
these 2 classes should be annotated with @Component or whatever you want spring stereotype

Then in CService bean you can add in constructor argument a List
Spring will wire theses 2 implementations in your bean